# How can I share a Virtual Machine between computers using something like Dropbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, sync, dropbox

I'd like to be able to create a virtual machine and have it 'synced' to another computer via a service like Dropbox.

The scenario here is: I have a computer at home, and a computer at work. I use a virtual machine in both environments to test software and often have to configure that VM (which is time consuming) before testing it.

Ideally, I'd be able to make minor changes in either location, have those changes sync'd up, and be able to just start up the machine in either spot.

I know I'd have to shut it down or hibernate it in either location before using it in the other.

The issue here comes to this: When making changes to a VM, it changes the file that represents the *entire* disk image. Is there a piece of virtualization software that saves changes in a more incremental fashion, so the syncing is much quicker using something like Dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more digging and found [this solution already posted.](https://superuser.com/questions/408095/how-to-maintain-a-small-differential-virtualbox-hard-drive)

Basically, it seems like I can create a "base image" of the system and have Dropbox sync that once, and then setup Virtualbox to make only incremental changes on top of it in either location. This should work perfectly!